# Twitter API V2 - Increase Rate Limit and Get Rate Limit Status

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm using following Twitter APIs

1. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets
2. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/retweets/api-reference/post-users-id-retweets
3. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/api-reference/post-users-source_user_id-following

The rate limit for these APIs are https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits here.

[Twitter API Rate Limit Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1cre.png)

The solutions I needed:

1. How can I increase the APIs rate limit?
2. I'm using https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/developer-utilities/rate-limit-status/api-reference/get-application-rate_limit_status API to get the APIs usage status, but it's returning same value in limit and remaining field. How can I get the exact usage details of APIs?
3. How I can get the daily API APP limits? The API seems to be returning 15 minutes limits, but I need to know how much app limit quota is remaining.

Comment: You cannot increase the API rate limit. Any attempt to subvert it would go against Twitter's ToS and could get you banned.

Comment: As for the second question, please show your code. Without knowing how you're using it, we won't be able to troubleshoot it. Make sure you redact any credentials when you post the code.

Comment: @aynber Also, how I can get the daily API APP limits? The API seems to be returning 15 minutes limits, but I need to know how much app limit quota is remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The post limits (Tweets, retweets, Direct Messages etc) are per-user quota. You can find out more about them from [Twitter’s help pages](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits).

> The current technical limits for accounts are:
>
> - Direct Messages (daily): The limit is 1,000 messages sent per day.
> - Tweets: 2,400 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as Tweets.

These limits are shared across all of the apps a user might use within a day. There is no API endpoint or header that shows what the current quota is - you have to account for this in your code.